# Xamarin Forms pull async table.CreateQuery() has OFFSET added by default

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, synchronization

Wonder if anyone has seen this before, and if so how they sorted it

I do a pull async on azure data in Xamarin Forms

```
if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected) { return; }
                table = Client.GetSyncTable<T>();
                var pullOptions = new PullOptions() { MaxPageSize = 100 };

                IMobileServiceTableQuery<T> query = table.CreateQuery();
                if(Client.SyncContext.IsInitialized)
                await table.PullAsync("qryAllEvents", query, pullOptions);
```

I know that this should bring back 5 records.

On checking the Sql Profiler and putting breakpoints in the node.js back end, I can see that 2 queries are run, one with OFFSET 0 and one with OFFSET 5, so it's removing all 5 records.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Events] WHERE ([updatedAt] >= @p1) ORDER BY [updatedAt] OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY; ',@params=N'@p1 datetimeoffset(7)',@p1='1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00'


SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Events] WHERE ([updatedAt] >= @p1) ORDER BY [updatedAt] OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY; ',@params=N'@p1 datetimeoffset(7)',@p1='1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00'
```

How does this OFFSET end up in the query resulting from `table.CreateQuery()` and is there any way I can prevent this so I get my rows returned?

Comment: Are you using PurgeAsync too with same data?

Comment: no, I don't want to purge only pull what's missing from local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How does this OFFSET end up in the query resulting from table.CreateQuery()...?*

The SDK sets the offset equal to the pull cursor position.

Taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/e68da427e0e455cd77f5915a75a9cfe93d028aa6/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore/SqlQueryFormatter.cs#L117).

```
if (offset.HasValue)
{
    this.sql.AppendFormat(" OFFSET {0}", offset.Value);
}
```

Also taken from [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/e68da427e0e455cd77f5915a75a9cfe93d028aa6/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Table/Sync/Queue/Actions/PullCursor.cs#L22).

```
internal class PullCursor
{
    public int Position
    {
        get { return this.initialSkip + this.totalRead; }
    }
```

*...is there any way I can prevent this so I get my rows returned?*

Your first query runs with no offset (cursor.Position is 0), then the SDK increments the offset by the total read. The fact the SDK is incrementing the total read tells me you ARE getting rows returned. I think something is going wrong when the SDK receives the results and persists to local store. Here's a similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238416/using-mobileservice-getsynctable-pullasync-trouble) to yours. One reply suggests enabling SQLite logging for more info and also explains the reason for the two API calls.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, just one final thing though - I can run the 2 resulting queries in management studio and obviously the 1st with no offset returns what I expect, the 5 records, I run the 2nd and nothing returns.  So if nothing returns from this 2nd query, how is data ever going to get back to the app, if the SDK increments the offset?

Comment: When the SDK stops receiving results, it stops pulling. Have a look at this do-while loop (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/e68da427e0e455cd77f5915a75a9cfe93d028aa6/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Table/Sync/Queue/Actions/PullAction.cs#L72). If you could drop a breakpoint at line 82 and inspect the result, I imagine you'd see your values, the code would loop, read again, see 0 results, and exit.